# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' during serving video file

Tags: connection, html5-video, django-2.1

I have read several questions similar to this. However, their problem was `broken pipe`, which is not applicable to my question. I would appreciate your help. I am trying to serve a video file in html template, using django. The model looks like this:

```
Class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    video_link = models.FileField(upload_to="videos", blank=True, null=True)
    ....
    # more fields go here
```

The "videos" directory is defined under media and media root is defined in settings. Images, for example, are served without exception.

In the HTML template, I use this code:

```
<video width="100%" height="300" controls>
                            <source src="{{ lesson.video_link.url }}" type="video/mp4">
                            <source src="{{ lesson.video_link.url }}" type="video/ogg">

                            Your browser does not support the video tag.
         </video>
```

When I click on the URL of the video, it plays, but I get the following exception. I am posting the full stack:

```
    [12/Apr/2019 22:17:31] "GET /media/videos/test_video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.0.108', 41410)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/mohammed/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/mohammed/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/mohammed/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/home/mohammed/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

Any help is highly appreciated.